# How to upload files on localhost Google App Engine running PHP 7.2?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, localhost, google-cloud-storage, php-7.2

I'm trying to implement the ability for a user to upload an image. I'll save that image to Google Storage. Then I'll use the GoogleStorageTools to get a public servable URL for the image so I can display it on my site.

I need to test this on localhost though. When I was previously using php5.5, I could use the dev_appserver.py and it would mimic the `gs://` integration and let me create and interact with files as if I was running in the cloud.

However, I'm using php7.2 for this app which can't use the dev_appserver.py, I just have to run through php's built-in webserver. When I try to upload the file, I get a Google Storage error. This is the code in my script that receives the post with the uploaded file:

```
$storage = new StorageClient();
$storage->registerStreamWrapper();

$basefilename = uniqid().'-'.sanitize_string($_FILES['imagefile']['name']);

$gsfilepath = 'gs://#default#/images/'.$basefilename;

if ( ! move_uploaded_file($_FILES[ 'imagefile' ]['tmp_name'], $gsfilepath)) {
    error_log('Failed to move uploaded file. ' . $_FILES[ 'imagefile' ]['tmp_name'] . ' => ' . $gsfilepath);
}
```

These are the errors I get when I try to run the `move_uploaded_file()` code:

> Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\NotFoundException: Client error: `POST
>   https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b//o?uploadType=resumable`
>   resulted in a `404 Not Found` response: Not Found in
>   /Users/kenny/myproject/trunk/server/gae/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapper.php
>   on line 263
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\NotFoundException:
>   Client error: `POST
>   https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b//o?uploadType=resumable`
>   resulted in a `404 Not Found` response: Not Found in
>   /Users/kenny/myproject/trunk/server/gae/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/RequestWrapper.php
>   on line 263
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   '/private/var/folders/1k/8xt74j593ss9yxbtqrv925j40000gp/T/phpKsSN6q'
>   to 'gs://#default#/images/5c1be56fd752d-hold-on-to-your-butts.png' in
>   /Users/kenny/myproject/trunk/server/gae/testupload-upload.php on line
>   11

Answer (score 0):

The bucket name `#default#` isn't valid in the Cloud Storage Stream Wrapper. As you can see in the error, the URI which the library is posting to is missing the Bucket ID.

To see why, refer to the [`StreamWrapper::openPath()`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-storage/blob/6e2ea113a802f95f3779931e5446c42afbd75cb8/src/StreamWrapper.php#L499-L503) method in `google/cloud-storage`.

The bucket name is represented as the `host` key in the `parse_url` return value. As is proved below, the gs URI you're providing is causing `parse_url` to fail:

```
php > $url = 'gs://#default/foo';
php > var_dump(parse_url($url));
bool(false)
```

I assume `#default#` is a helper which works in certain circumstances. Try providing the real bucket ID in the gs URI.

Comment: What is the real bucket if I'm running on localhost? `#default#` as the bucket DID work when I was running with php 5.5 with the `dev_appserver.py`.

Comment: If I do put in the proper bucket that would be used when it will eventually run in the cloud, then it just gives me a 401 Not Authorized error which I think is to be expected, because it can't authorize me coming from some random location (i.e. my localhost).

Comment: You can determine the proper bucket name in the Cloud Storage Console. If you're getting Unauthorized errors, it may be because you don't have authentication configured locally. The easiest way (and the way which will minimize code changes between your local environment and AppEngine would be using Application Default Credentials, setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable with the path to your service account keyfile. See here for more details: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have much knowledge of how `dev_appserver.py` works. If `#default#` worked with the PHP stream wrapper in 5.5, it suggests that the python script must have been rewriting it to the proper bucket name prior to executing.